# Is it possible to pair EZ Publish 5 to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, ezpublish

We have an EZ Publish 5 already operational with an Oracle 11g database as a persistence backend.
We planned to get rid of Oracle and we know that we could use Postgresql for sure as a new RDBMS, but we also planned to use MongoDB whenever it's possible.
So the question is: Can we pair EZ Publish 5 to a MongoDB NoSQL database ?

Comment: In my humble opinion, a database server which is not able to handle transactions or reference contraints should not be used with eZ Publish.
I suggest you use PostgreSQL instead.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: You cannot now as there is no MongoDB driver implemented.

There was a [NoSQL Driver](http://share.ez.no/blogs/ez/ez-publish-5-platform-a-new-era-for-and-by-our-community/%28page%29/2) planned in the 5.x series, but it is not yet implemented in the latest [eZ Publish 2013.06](http://share.ez.no/blogs/community-project-board/ez-publish-community-project-2013.06-is-now-available).

With the [official roadmap](http://ez.no/Resources/Software/Roadmap-and-lifecycle) not being updated since the 4.6 release, it hard to guess when the NoSQL driver will be implemented, and if MongoDB will be supported.

Theorically, as the new persistence API make it "easier" to add new storage drivers, you could write a custom MongoDB storage driver.
But in practice implementing a storage driver is quite complex and resource consuming.

Contacting the eZ Systems office in your region and directly ask them when a MongoDB driver will be available might be fastest way to get a clear answer.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it seems now clear to me that it's going to be quite difficult to use MongoDB with eZ Publish. I'm going to go ahead and contact eZ Publish in Paris to find out if they planned a release supporting MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible as there is no storage engine implemented for MongoDB.

It is indeed planned to implement a NoSQL engine, but there is no version tag on this for now.

However, the new persistence API makes it possible to "easily" implement such a storage engine, but you will be limited by the fact that eZ Publish 5 still uses the legacy back office which runs in the legacy stack (so with 4.x infrastructure which is not compatible with NoSQL).
In short: Implementing a new storage engine will make it only accessible from Public API and REST API.

Comment: Useful information indeed. I guess I'll hold on till I get better perspectives with eZPublish and NoSQL together.

Answer (score 0):

Since ez5 is a symfony application you can achieve this the symfony way
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

just remember they have renamed the app folder and the appkernel.php.
Haven't tried it yet though